# Saving an array of ints then loading certain elements

Tags: java, input, output, 2d-games

I'm making a tile based game with a very large map so i don't want to have the whole map saved in memory so i want to save the map and load only a part of it at once how can i do this??

i want to save the map as an array of integers and split the integer in half like:

```
int id = basetile | abovetile << 8
```

at the moment i am just using an array of chunks each with an array of tiles so i can just update chunks i need too but i have noticed i am using allot of memory for such a simple thing

edit:

how would i edit a value that u have put()

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File f = new File("file.sav");
    f.delete();

    try (FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw").getChannel()){

        long buffersize = 100;

        MappedByteBuffer mem = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, buffersize);

        mem.put(new byte[] {6, 4, 2});
        mem.flip();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

how

Comment: What code have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  Have you tried memory mapped files as this avoids loading any of the data on to the heap?

Comment: If `basetile` fits into 8 bits, then you may be able to use a `byte[]` rather than an `int[]`. This reduces memory usage by factor of 4, but `byte[]` can be tricky to use because `byte` is signed (values range from -128 to 127 rather than 0 to 255).

Comment: Peter Lawrey's suggestion is definitely worth a try. Plus, by wrapping a `ByteBuffer` with a `ShortBuffer` or  an `IntBuffer` you can easily spend different amounts of memory on each of your tiles.

Answer (score 0):

i found this code i very slightly edited it

```
public static MappedByteBuffer save(String path, int[] data, int size) {
    try (FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw").getChannel()) {

        MappedByteBuffer mbb = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, size);
        mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            mbb.putInt(data[i]);
        }
        channel.close();

        return mbb;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("IOException : " + e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static int[] load(String path, int size, int offs) {

    try (FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r").getChannel()) {
        MappedByteBuffer mbb2 = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
        mbb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        int[] data = new int[(int) channel.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = mbb2.getInt(i + offs);
        }
        channel.close();

        return data;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;

}
```

thanks for the name of this method